# put spans on the same line with buttons

Tags: html, css

I have some kind of a panel with some buttons and spans (to show some info as text). The problem is I can't put all the elements of that panel on the same line. It looks like the row of spans are a bit lower than the buttons row.

```css
#workspace {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -400px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#dashb {
  background-color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 40px;
}

.btn {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFBF00;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#info2 {
  margin-top: -20px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFBF00;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="workspace">

  <div id="dashb">
    <button id="populate" class="btn" onclick="random">RANDOM</button>
    <button id="start" class="btn" onclick="start">START</button>
    <button id="pause" class="btn" onclick="pause">PAUSE</button>
    <button id="next" class="btn" onclick="next()">NEXT</button>

    <span id="info1" class="btn">0</span>

    <span id="info2" style="width: 120px;">0</span>
  </div>


</div>
```

I've tried to use **btn** style to **info1** and made it's own for **info2**. Neither works.

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: flex;` to wrap instead `use display:inline-block` to each one.

Also use `margin-top: 10px;` to `#info2` instead  `margin-top: -20px;`

```css
#workspace {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -400px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#dashb {
  background-color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 40px;
display: flex;
}

.btn {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFBF00;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;

}

#info2 {
   margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFBF00;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="workspace">

  <div id="dashb">
    <button id="populate" class="btn" onclick="random">RANDOM</button>
    <button id="start" class="btn" onclick="start">START</button>
    <button id="pause" class="btn" onclick="pause">PAUSE</button>
    <button id="next" class="btn" onclick="next()">NEXT</button>

    <span id="info1" class="btn">0</span>

    <span id="info2" style="width: 120px;">0</span>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flex box layout method so that all the elements in the container be in the same line. Here the container is dahsb and the itmes are all the btn and spans in it.

```
#dashb{
    display:flex;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to use ".btn" class for everything in menu then add `line-height` equal to height of elements in it 30px it this case and to make them in one row add `vertical-align: top;` to align them to top of parent container

```
.btn {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFBF00;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;

  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```css
.btn {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFBF00;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;

  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 30px;
}
#workspace {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -400px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#dashb {
  background-color: firebrick;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="workspace">

      <div id="dashb">
        <button id="populate" class="btn" onclick="random">RANDOM</button>
        <button id="start" class="btn" onclick="start">START</button>
        <button id="pause" class="btn" onclick="pause">PAUSE</button>
        <button id="next" class="btn" onclick="next()">NEXT</button>

        <span id="info1" class="btn">0</span>

        <span id="info2" class="btn" style="width: 120px;">0</span>
      </div>

    </div>
```

SOURCE : 
[vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)